# How to run webdriver script on firefox, chrome and IE parallaly in IntellijIdea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver, junit4

I have created a framework in IntellijIdea for some simple functionality like Google Search, Gmail Registration and Gmail Login.
I tried to run my script on IE, chrome and firefox separately. It is working fine.
Now I want to run the script on all above browsers parallel y.
Can anyone help me to write a piece of code for the same???
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Test
public void test() throws Exception
{
    WebDriver fireFoxDriver = null;
    WebDriver chromeDriver = null;
    WebDriver internetExplorerDriver = null;

    //FireFox Driver
        fireFoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
        fireFoxDriver.get("http://yahoo.com");
        System.out.println("Firefox Windows Title = " + fireFoxDriver.getTitle());

        //Chrome Driver
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\chromedriver.exe" );
        chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        chromeDriver.get("http://gmail.com");
        System.out.println("Chrome Windows Title = " + chromeDriver.getTitle());

        //IE Driver. NOTE: Turn off the protected mode for all Zones ( Internet / Local intranet / Trusted Sites / Restricted Sites ) or else the browser fails to launch
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\IEDriverServer.exe");

        //Without the following two lines of code I was getting the following exception on Windows 7 & IE 9:
        //org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Browser zoom level was set to 79%. It should be set to 100% (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
         DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
         caps.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);

        internetExplorerDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
        internetExplorerDriver.manage().window().maximize();
        internetExplorerDriver.get("http://nseindia.com");
        System.out.println("IE Windows title = " + internetExplorerDriver.getTitle());
        internetExplorerDriver.quit();
        fireFoxDriver.quit();chromeDriver.quit();

}
```

Comment: Neeraj, Thanks for your reply. I wanted script for parallel execution of webdriver script across mentioned browsers. This is good script provided by you, but it can be better with only one WebDriver variable   used with control flow instead of three. Pls help.

Comment: Ah! I got your point now. Please go through http://www.abodeqa.com/2013/02/21/how-to-execute-selenium-webdriver-test-cases-parallel-in-multiple-browser-using-testng-parameter-annotation/  I think this is what you are looking for. Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks neeraj...!! That is looking good with parameter annotation. Parameter annotation comes with TestNG. I have developed framework in IntellijIdea. Please suggest references for IntellijIdea Framework.